# JSF DataTable Select One Row Using Radio Button

Tags: jsf, radio-button

I am using JSF 1.1 and I have a ice:datatable with rows getting fetched from backing bean.
To select the row for editing I have a radio button for that row.
When I select the row using the radio button I am getting the following error.

```
radio.name is undefined
```

In my page I am calling the javascript as follows

```
<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="none" valueChangeListener="#{bean.setSelectedItem}"
                onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="null" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Any my javascript function

```
function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
    var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
    var el = radio.form.elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
            el[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
    radio.checked = true;
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently IceFaces doesn't generate `name` attribute for the radio button or doesn't put `onclick` on the generated `<input type="radio">` element. Try using `id` instead. Replace `radio.name` in JavaScript code by `radio.id`. If in vain, you need to check the generated HTML output (open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*) and alter the JS code accordingly.

Comment: Hi,
I replaced radio.name with radio.id. However now I am getting an error 
    radio.form is undefined
    var elements = radio.form.elements; 
Sorry I couldn't do anything when I looked the source of html.
The following is my modified javascript. Kindly need your help to resolve my error.

Comment: Here is my code 
function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
        var id = radio.id.substring(radio.id.lastIndexOf(':'));    
        var elements = radio.form.elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].name.substring(elements[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                elements[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
        radio.checked = true;
    }

Comment: Then IceFaces isn't putting the `onclick` on the radio buttons at all, but on some other element. Sorry, I can't help you further in detail since I don't do IceFaces. You need to read the generated HTML output and change the JS code accordingly.

Comment: When I put alert('id '+id);, I could see value of id. So that means onclick works for radio button?

Comment: It can also be an entirely different HTML element which already has an `id`. Once again, check the generated HTML source and change JS code accordingly. This is not a JSF problem per se. JavaScript code knows nothing about JSF source code. The only which JavaScript can see, access and modify is the HTML code. I can't tell from top of head how the generated HTML of IceFaces look like, so I can't help you further in detail.

Comment: You posted a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875847/how-to-get-selected-icefaces-datatable-row-using-radiobutton You should actually not leave questions unanswered and post another one. You should actually update your current question to include more detail to solve the problem. For example a relevant excerpt of the generated HTML so that we can help in providing the right JavaScript for this.

Comment: Sorry about this as I leave this question unanswered. Will keep this in mind for future.