# How to get selected icefaces datatable row using radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, jsf, radio-button, icefaces

How can I select a row in icefaces datatable using radio button?

I tried with the following

```
<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="none" valueChangeListener="#{bean.setSelectedItem}"
                onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="null" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
```

And my javascript

```
function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
    var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
    var el = radio.form.elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
            el[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
    radio.checked = true;
}
```

In another post I got an answer that I should replace form.name with form.id. However after that I am getting error

```
radio.form is undefined 
var elements = radio.form.elements;
```

Could someone help me how to resolve this issue.

I would like to select one row in icefaces datatable using radio button.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Posting my generated html source

See here is jsf code for radio button

```
<h:selectOneRadio  valueChangeListener="#{bean.setSelectedItem}"
id="reqselect" onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);">
<f:selectItem itemValue="null" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

My heartfelt apologies for posting in correct html source, I was testing some thing else and thus wrong source got posted. Pasted below is my correct html source, kindly see if you could find something.

Comment: This question is unanswerable by non-IceFaces users if you don't show the generated HTML. JavaScript runs in webbrowser on HTML, not in webserver on JSF.

Comment: Original question here: [JSF DataTable Select One Row Using Radio Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871423/jsf-datatable-select-one-row-using-radio-button)

Comment: The generated code shows that it's in the `onkeypress`, but in JSF you've put it in `onclick`. Huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ice:selectOneRadio with spread layout:

```
<ice:selectOneRadio id="myRadioId" layout="spread" ... /> 
<ice:dataTable ... >
    <ice:column ...>
        <ice:radio for="myRadioId" ... />
    </ice:column>
    ...
</ice:dataTable>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be partially working. Now I need to pass the row id to my backing bean, that is left. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the generated HTML of each radio button look like:

```
<table id="crud:tab_cr:9:_id53" border="0" onkeypress="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="crud:tab_cr:9:_id53" id="crud:tab_cr:9:_id53:_1" value="null" onkeypress="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);Ice.util.radioCheckboxEnter(form,this,event);" />
      <label for="crud:tab_cr:9:_id53:_1">null</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So IceFaces is apparently rendering a whole HTML table around the radio button and putting the JS function on the `<table>` as well. The JS function clearly doesn't belong there at all (apart from the fact that `onkeypress` is incorrect, it should be `onclick`).

The `<h:selectOneRadio>` doesn't render a whole table around by default. This can only mean that you were **actually** using `<ice:selectOneRadio>` or that the IceFaces replaced the standard renderer for `<h:selectOneRadio>`. You need to fix it in this corner. Either replace by `<h:selectOneRadio>` or report a bug to IceFaces guys that their radio renderer is incorrectly putting the JS function on `<table>` element as well.

Comment: I have added correct html source above, apologies for posting in correct html source.

Comment: I am unable to call setSelectedItem method which is specified in valueChangeListener="#{bean.setSelectedItem}"